# Painting a group of objects in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, draw, paint

I'm pretty new to Java and the GUI world. Right now I'm trying to create a really basic space shooter. To create it I started creating a `JFrame`, in which I've later on put a personal extension of a `JPanel` called `GamePanel`, on which I'm now trying to display all my components. Until here it's all pretty clear, the problem comes now: I have my `GamePanel` in which I display my player, and on the `KeyEvent` of pressing S the player should shoot the Bullets. I've managed the bullets as an Array, called `Shooter[]`, of `Bullet` Objects, created by myself this way:

```
public class Bullet implements ActionListener{

    Timer Time = new Timer(20, this);

    private int BulletY = 430;
    public int PlayerX;
    public Rectangle Bound = new Rectangle();

    public Bullet(int playerx) {
        this.PlayerX = playerx;
        Time.start();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(PlayerX + 2, BulletY, 3, 10);

        g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (Time.isRunning()) {
            BulletY = BulletY - 5;
            Bound = new Rectangle (PlayerX + 2, BulletY, 3, 10);
        }
    }

}
```

I thought that calling the draw method in the `GamePanel`'s `paint()` method would have allowed me to display both all the bullets shot and the player. What actually happens is that at the start it seems allright, but when I press S the player disappears and just one bullet is shot. Can you explain me why? This is how my `paint()` method looks like:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

        for(int i = 0; i < BulletsCounter; i++) {
            Shooter[i].draw(g);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(PlayerX, PlayerY, 20, 20);

        //System.out.println("Here I should have painted the player...");

        g.dispose();
    }
```

`BulletsCounter` is a counter I've created to avoid any `NullPointerException`s in painting the whole array, it increases when S is pressed and so another bullet of the array is initialized and shot.
Thank you for your patience, I'm new to the site, so warn me for any mistake.

Comment: don't call g.dispose() + follow the java camel-case naming convention: Upper case for classes and lower cases for attributes. Not following the name convention makes your code difficult to read.

Comment: @Chocksmith: actually, it *is* OK to call `Graphics#dispose()` on a Graphics object that you the coder have obtained, e.g., `Graphics g = myBufferedImage.getGraphics();`, and in fact, you *should* dispose of such a resource after done using it  in order to conserve resources, but you shouldn't call `.dispose()` on a Graphics object given to you by the JVM, and this distinction is important, which is why I have mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: *would have allowed me to display both all the bullets shot and the player.* - yes it should work if you array contains multiple bullet objects. You need to post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Changing the paint() into paintComponent() + removing g.dispose() has fixed the problem, plus you have teached me a lot, thank you so much, you've been amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've several significant problems, the biggest given first:

- You're disposing a Graphics object given to you by the JVM. Never do this as this will break the painting chain. Instead, only dispose of a Graphics object that you yourself have created.
- You're drawing within paint which is not good for several reasons, but especially bad for animation since you don't have automatic double buffering of the image
- You don't call the super painting method within your override and thus don't allow the JPanel to do house-keeping painting.

Recommendations:

- Don't dispose of the Graphics object, not unless you, yourself, create it, for example if you extract one from a BufferedImage.
- Override the JPanel's paintComponent method, not its paint method to give you double buffering and smoother animation.
- And call `super.paintComponent(g)` first thing in your override to allow for housekeeping painting